# Web.config - Rewrite Rule на файл PHP - НЕ обрабатывает PHP-код

Tags: php, iis, windows-server, rewrite

Имеется VPS - Windows Server 2016.

В файле web.config следующий код:

```
<rule name="Test">
  <match url="test.html$"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/php/test.php" />
</rule>
```

Проблема в том, что web.config перенаправляет на файл test.php, но этот файл не обрабатывается как PHP (выдаёт исходный код на странице).

Что сделать, чтобы обрабатывалось как PHP? Какая-то настройка на сервере?

Буду крайне благодарен за помощь!

Comment: установить php на сервер, настроить fastCGI в IIS, затем настроить сопоставление расширения `.php`

Comment: Стоило проговорить, что это уже сделано. На сайтах всё работает. Но при перенаправлении из web.config - не работает. Я вроде все настройки в диспетчере служб IIS облазил, ничего, что можно поправить не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно включить FastCGI на IIS. Затем изменить под него настройки в php.ini и настроить сопоставление обработчика для расширения php.

Подробная [инструкция](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/install.windows.legacy.index.php#install.windows.legacy.iis7) приведена в официальной документации.

А, вообще самый просто способ поставить PHP на IIS это воспользоваться Microsoft Web Platform Installer.

Comment: Пожалуй, стоило проговорить, что PHP (FastCgiModule) на сервере настроен (на сайтах всё работает). Но вот именно при перенаправлении из web.config - не работает.

Comment: А, Вы уверены, что запрос в правиле редиректа сопоставлен с PHP
 интерпретатором? Ведь Вы получает html, а перенаправляете его на PHP.

Comment: Скорее всего, вы правильно говорите. Можете подсказать, как сопоставить с PHP интерпретатором. Вообще, в ходе экспериментов выяснил, что да, HTML и JS обрабатываются. PHP - нет.

Comment: Пример сопоставления обработчика есть инструкции по ссылке в ответе. По хорошему, у /Вас должно отличаться только расширение. Более точно не могу подсказать, т.к. в последнее время PHP использую только на Linux ( там с ним головной боли меньше).

Comment: Хорошо, покопаюсь. К слову, у меня есть Windows-хостинг (а то VPS). Так там никаких проблем. Файл web.config использовал один и тот же.

Comment: Всякое, конечно может быть. Многое зависит и от самого хоста и от проектов, которые хостятся. Но, просто из опыта, сейчас под виндой PHP использую максимум для разработки.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему нашёл. Оказалась "внезапной"...

Заметил, что часть PHP кода в файле test.php (при перенаправлении из web.config) почему-то  комментируется. Попробовал в начале кода вместо `<?` указать `<?php`. И всё заработало...

Оказалось, что в php.ini по умолчанию было включено "short_open_tag = Off"

Сделал "On" - всё работает... Капец)

В любом случае, благодарю Streletz за участие. Общение помогает мыслить)